# Find annotation based error that leads to cannot find symbol class of all generated class

Tags: android, annotations

Whenever an annotation fails for any reason (not supported parameter or missing resource id), the result will be that android studio prints out a lot of errors like following (it will print out ALL generated classes although all of them will exist!!!):

```
cannot find symbol class ...
```

**Root causes**

The root causes I know are for example following:

1. using icepick parceler library:

   ```
   @State
   public List<String> data= null; // should be ArrayList, because List is not Parcelable nor Serialisable
   ```
2. using the well-known butterknife library:

   ```
   @InjectView(R.id.view)
   private View view; // should be public or default!
   ```

**Question**

How to find out the root cause if something like this happens?